# Brightness/Contrast Difference from PC to YouTube

Tags: youtube, davinci-resolve

So I have a trailer I've been working on, I did everything in Davinci Resolve 12. When I convert the video using Handbrake everything looks fine, but when I upload it to YouTube, either there's a ton more contrast, or gray is being remaped to black, not sure, but the photos below should show what I'm talking about.

I've done quite a bit of research, and the closest I've come is there might be something wrong with the way YouTube treats color spaces in conjunction with how I converted it. Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:** Just finished uploading a version I converted with MPEG Streamclip, and the color looks great, though it was washed out on my PC. It came out as a ~200MB file for just a few seconds at 100% though, so not fun to upload. Looked just as crisp with Handbrake at ~27MB. Any way to take the color/brightness stuff from Streamclip and use it with Handbrake?

YouTube:
[image]
VLC on my PC:
[image]

Comment: Did you find out what was causing the shift? I have the same problem - Prores mov looks great in QT and VLC but washed out when uploaded to YT.

Comment: @Pedr No, but what I ended up doing is to use DaVinci's YouTube output setting on the deliver page, which seems to work great. There's also a "Data level" setting on that page under video which makes the footage look different.

Comment: Thanks. I had assumed that converting to H264 before upload would result in a lower quality video because YouTube will re-encode it.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Handbrake is outputting full range but flagging it as video levels, so the Handbrake output actually has Y=0 as black and Y=255 as white but the flag is telling Youtube that Y=16 is black and Y=235 is white.

If you upload a short segment (3-5s) of both your Handbrake input and output, that can be confirmed.

Comment: That was what I thought. I just uploaded the original MOV from Davinci and it looks just like the Handbrake file.

Comment: Not clear to me. You said that Handbrake looked fine locally but expanded on Youtube, so does the MOV on YT look like Handbrake on PC or YT?

Comment: Sorry, the MOV acts the same as the Handbrake file, in that locally it looks fine, but on YouTube it looks the same as the Handbrake file does when uploaded to YouTube.